# Вывод сообщений онлайн чатом на экран

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Есть страница chat.html на которой есть поле ввода сообщения, кнопка отправки и поле вывода(таблица).До перехода на эту страницу пользователь авторизуется на другой(имя сохраняется сессией) и на chat.html после введения пользователем сообщения и нажатия кнопки отправки в этой таблице должно выводиться время, имя и само сообщение.

Вот `AJAX` на отправку самого сообщения в `php` и если все прошло успешно то идет вывод на экран.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#easyForm').submit(function() {
    var text = $('#text').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/chat_script.php',
      data: {
        message: text
      },
      success: function(arr) {
        $('#time').html(arr.time);
        $('#name').html(arr.user);
        $('#message').html(arr.message);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
table#messages {
  width: 490px;
  height: 260px;
  background: #fffecd;
  border: none;
}

td#time,
td#name {
  width: 100px;
}

td#name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div#inputs {
  width: 495px;
}

form#text_submit {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

input#text {
  width: 370px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #fffecd;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

input#submit {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 21px;
  margin-top: 21px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #635960;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputs">
  <table id="messages">
    <tr>
      <td id="time"></td>
      <td id="name"></td>
      <td id="message"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <form method="POST" id="easyForm">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Вот `php`, в `AJAX` данные возвращаются в виде json строки. Подскажите, что я не так делаю?

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$time = date('H:i:s');

$file = "../data/messages.json";
$json_content = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

$content = array();

if(is_array($json_content)) {
    $content = $json_content;
}

if (!empty($message)) {
    $content[] = array("time" => $time, "user" => $user, "message"  => $message);

    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($content, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),FILE_APPEND);

}

echo json_encode($content);
?>
```

Ошибка

```
VM45:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 18
at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (message.js:14)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at A (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Ошибка при JSON.parse

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (message.js:18)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at A (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
success @ message.js:18
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
A @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
```

Cодержание `$content - {"time":"13:23:09","user":"qwe","message":"qwe"}`

Comment: И один баг как я понимаю, зачем написать так? `$content[] = array("time" => '$time', "user" => '$user', "message"  => '$message');` Так у вас получается двумерный массив, вот такого вида `Array ( [0] => Array ( [time] => $time [user] => $user [message] => $message ) )`;
Надо так `$content = array("time" => '$time', "user" => '$user', "message"  => '$message');`

Comment: Проблема именно в этом, так вы даете `ajax` запросу массив с одним значением  в которой ваша строка `[{"time":"$time","user":"$user","message":"$message"}]`.

Comment: Что у вас содержится в переменных вот этого массива? `array("time" => $time, "user" => $user, "message"  => $message);` это то же добавь в вопрос я посмотрю. Это из за значений переменных

Comment: И пробуй вот так то же `JSON.parse(json);`. Хочу его ошибку увидеть

Comment: `{"time":"13:23:09","user":"qwe","message":"qwe"}` это содержание `$content` ? или ответа `ajax` запроса `arr`?

Comment: Ответа само собой, извините.

Comment: Я исправил все, проблема в том что мой localhost не хотел обновлять введенные мной правки в AJAX  пока я не зашел в скрипт непосредственно через него и не обновил странницу. Теперь всё выводиться но после вывода сообщения, я ввожу другое и оно заменяет первое.Как сделать так что бы они вообще не пропадали с таблицы а только добавлялись?

Comment: Добавил пример в конец ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ответ строка `json` а вы пытаетесь обработать его как `object`.
До обработки надо сделать парсинг:

Пример кода:

```js
    var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}';
    obj = JSON.parse(json);

    console.log(obj.count);
```

А это парсинг с помощью `jQuery`։

```js
var json = '{"result":true,"count":8567}';
obj = $.parseJSON(json);

console.log(obj.count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Парсинг вашего полученного ответа:

```js
var json = '{"time":"13:23:09","user":"qwe","message":"qwe"}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.user);
```

С вашим кодом будет так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#easyForm').submit(function() {
    var text = $('#text').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/chat_script.php',
      data: {
        message: text
      },
      success: function(arr) {
        arr = JSON.parse(arr);
        $('#time').html(arr.time);
        $('#name').html(arr.user);
        $('#message').html(arr.message);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Измените кусок вашего `html` таким образом:

```
<div id="inputs">
  <table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time"></td>
      <td class="name"></td>
      <td class="message"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <form method="POST" id="easyForm">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Для класса `mess_hide` добавьте `css` ՝․mess_hide{display: none;}՝.

А `success` в `ajax` запросе измените вот так:

```
$('#messages').append($('.mess_hide').clone().addClass('mess_tmp').removeClass('mess_hide'));

$('.mess_tmp>.time').html(arr.time);
$('.mess_tmp>.name').html(arr.user);
$('.mess_tmp>.message').html(arr.message);
$('.mess_tmp').removeClass('mess_tmp');
```

Пример:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var json = '{"time":"13:23:09","user":"qwe","message":"qwe"}';
    arr = JSON.parse(json);

    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.test').click(function(){
        $('#messages').append($('.mess_hide').clone().addClass('mess_tmp').removeClass('mess_hide'));

        $('.mess_tmp>.time').html(arr.time);
        $('.mess_tmp>.name').html(arr.user);
        $('.mess_tmp>.message').html(arr.message);
        $('.mess_tmp').removeClass('mess_tmp');
      });  
    });
    
</script>

<div id="inputs">
  <table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time"></td>
      <td class="name"></td>
      <td class="message"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button class="test">test</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, но это почему-то не работает.

Comment: @МаксимБуяков Посмотрите первую часть ответа, рабочий скрипт, оно работает, значит проблема еще и в другом, вместо `arr` заполните просто другую строку `json` и дайте в `success`, увидим парсинг не работает или проблема в другом.

Comment: исправил `$content`, сделал как вы написали и выбило ошибку. Её содержание прикрепил к заданию.

Comment: Происходит так что при переходе на страницу поля для вывода сообщений вообще нет, а когда ввожу и отправляю сообщение поле появляется, сообщения выводятся так: ввожу "привет", вывелось, потом ввожу "как дела" и оно выводиться но "привет" заменился на "как дела"

Comment: @МаксимБуяков Ответ обновлен, у тебя в `success` нет этой строки в конце `$('.mess_tmp').removeClass('mess_tmp');`.

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо)

Comment: А ещё, наверное, можно заменить `ajax` на `getJSON` и разбор сделает сам jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

Ваш скрипт не знает что он будет получать если вы возвращаете json, то вам необходмо в ajax({}) добавить dataType: "json"

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/chat_script.php',
      data: {
        message: text
      },
      dataType:"json",
      success: function(arr) {
        $('#time').html(arr.time);
        $('#name').html(arr.user);
        $('#message').html(arr.message);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Попробовал сделать как вы написали, но ничего не произошло: ввожу сообщение, нажимаю кнопку и всё, ничего не происходит.

Comment: Как вы можете работать со строкой `json` Как с `object` ?